# Remove properties from an object that are not declared in a type interface

Tags: typescript

I want to remove all properties from an object which are not declared in a specific type interface.

For example, let's assume that I have the following interface:

```
export interface CreateCustomerUserInput {
    fullname: string;
    email: string;
}
```

And I have the following object:

```
let obj = {fullname: 'AAA', email: 'aa@aa.com', phone: '111', address: 'XXX'};
```

But I want to create a new object with only properties declared in the type interface.
Here is the expected object:

```
let c = {fullname: 'AAA', email: 'aa@aa.com'}
```

Is there any good way to solve this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 9):

If I understand you correctly, you want to strip away all properties from an object that are not defined in a specific type interface.

Unfortunately, type interfaces are not available at runtime - meaning, they don't exist when running the JavaScript code. Therefore, there is no way to access reflective information about the type programmatically.

However, you might be successful by using a `class`. For example, let's assume you have the following class:

```
export class CreateCustomerUserInput {
    public fullname: string = "";
    public email: string = "";
}
```

You could create an instance of that class and iterate over its properties using a `for.. in` loop or with `Object.keys()`. Then you could strip away the properties of your given object by using `delete` for each property that is not available in the instance of your class.

For this to work, make sure **all** properties of the class are initialized after construction.

Another way is using TypeScript decorators with the experimental metadata flag, as explained here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html.

They preserve reflective information, but only for classes (or abstract classes)!