# How to cast a variable from one type to another?

Tags: typescript

I'm getting some data that has a metadata field in it that I'd like stripped out. It comes to me in typed variables like so:

```
type MainRecord = {
  id: string
  fieldOne: string
  related: RelatedRecord[]
  __typename: string
}

type RelatedRecord = {
  id: string
  fieldTwo: string
  __typename: string
}
```

I'm using Formik to update the records but I don't want the `__typename` fields included when I create the initial values for the form because trying to send the data to the server with the metadata included causes syntax errors for the query when I do. I have separate types for the Formik forms like so:

```
type MainFields = {
  id: string
  fieldOne: string
  related: RelatedFields[]
}

type RelatedFields = {
  id: string
  fieldTwo: string
}
```

My solution was to try to cast the `MainRecord` data as a `MainFields` object which seems like its working because `fields.__typename` is not a valid property and neither is `fields.related[0].__typename`.

```
const record: MainRecord = {
  id: "10",
  fieldOne: "Foo",
  __typename: "Main",
  related: [
    {
      id: "20",
      fieldTwo: "Bar",
      __typename: "Related"
    },
    {
      id: "21",
      fieldTwo: "Baz",
      __typename: "Related"
    },
  ]
}

const fields: MainFields = record // or "as MainFields"
```

However when you log the `fields` variable, the metadata is still there and it shouldn't be.

```
console.log("fields: ", fields);
```

I guess I could strip them out programmatically by hand but there's got to be a better way. Any ideas? I'm sure there's a typescript way of accomplishing this but I just don't know it.

Comment: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d - either filter or map or chain the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lodash's `omit` function, I found a way to do a recursive `omit` like so:

````js
function omitDeep(obj: any, keyToOmit: string) {
  _.forIn(obj, function (value, key) {
    if (_.isObject(value)) {
      omitDeep(value, keyToOmit);
    } else if (key === keyToOmit) {
          delete obj[key];
    }
  });
}
```js
````

Comment: Remember that you can do this easily today using the spread operator, as in `const { [keyToOmit]: _, ...rest } = obj`, where obj is the original value, keyToOmit is the property to "remove", _ is a variable name which is used as a discard, and ...rest is the remaining properties which can be used afterwards. (Although this is just one level deep)

Comment: Yeah I needed a solution that was more substantial which would be recursive. I actually tried a solution like this and it was going to be way more involved than I wanted. Spread operator is a good solution for something simple though, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think TypeScript will actually mutate whenever you use the `as` keyword, it will just treat it "as" the appropriate type in an "if you say so" type manner.

Your best bet really is to do a filter on the properties either with your own utility or something like lodash.

[Removing object properties with Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40329742)

See this question which seems to be considering something similar.

[Remove properties from an object that are not declared in a type interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51155239)

Comment: I've heard of lodash. I'll look into that. If you have a quick solution to fix this with lodash, please add it to your answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer.